# Why am I getting "This module has been removed" while creating an S3 bucket using Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

```
  - name: Create S3 bucket
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:
      - name: Creating S3 bucket
        s3: 
          key_name: LampKey
          bucket: biju-ansible-bucket
          mode: create
```

I am using the above code to create S3 bucket.

However when I run the above playbook, I get this error:

```
TASK [Creating S3 bucket] *****************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "This module has been removed. The module documentation for Ansible-2.6 may contain hints for 
porting"}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing module `s3` with `was_s3` resolved this error

```
  - name: Create S3 bucket
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:
      - name: Creating S3 bucket
        aws_s3: 
          aws_access_key: xx
          aws_secret_key: yy
          bucket: biju_ansible_bucket
          mode: create
```